# each all data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey I am trying to create a sort by picture,document,video. I have many div which contains data-extension,so my idea to take all attributes contains jpg,gif,png and i put visible and the other to hide.
My problem how to each multiple data attributes:
This is my structure

```
<div class="full-image" data-id="2"  data-image="jpg"><img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3"  data-image="png"><img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4"  data-image="jpg"><img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5"  data-image="mp4"><img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6"  data-image="gif"><img src=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop throught the divs, use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to check the `data-image` attribute and add the right class accordingly ( hidden or visible ) :

```js
const ext = ["jpg", "gif", "png"];

document.querySelectorAll('.full-image').forEach(div => {
  const className= ext.includes(div.dataset['image']) ? "visible" : "hide";
  
  div.classList.add(className);
});
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-image" data-id="2"  data-image="jpg">1<img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="3"  data-image="png">2<img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="4"  data-image="jpg">3<img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="5"  data-image="mp4">4<img src=""/>
<div class="full-image" data-id="6"  data-image="gif">5<img src=""/>
```

Comment: just a little problem if i choose video and then i choose pdf that nothing shows
 https://jsfiddle.net/thomas_david88/7ocuhnzd/22/

Comment: you'll have to remove the `hidden` class first, here's an updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lr41t85z/

Comment: please i come back to you ,there is a small error if i have for exemple in data-image="mp4,jpg" it is not displayed
https://jsfiddle.net/thomas_david88/zx7wakfq/4/

Comment: I changed the code is still not working
https://jsfiddle.net/thomas_david88/zx7wakfq/112/